# Does CnosDB support nested subqueries with aggregate functions or any equivalent solution?

Tags: sql, cnosdb

Currently, I cannot do this in CnosQL:

```
SELECT mean(max("speed")) FROM "wind" GROUP BY time(1m)
```

I would like to count the average value of the maximum speed per minute over a period of time.

Comment: What else have you tried? Can you use a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, CnosDB supports nested subqueries with aggregate functions.
You can try with

```
SELECT MEAN("max") FROM (SELECT MAX("speed") FROM "wind" GROUP BY time(1m) )
```

You use the wrong syntax of nested subqueries with aggregate functions.

The right syntax is:

```
SELECT_clause FROM ( SELECT_clause FROM ( SELECT_statement ) [...] ) [...]
```

Maybe you can try this again.

Comment: Where does that max inside MEAN("max") come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it supports. However, your query seems problematic for adding "" for the measurement name. TRY：

```
SELECT mean(max("speed")) FROM wind GROUP BY time(1m)
```